# Пропадает соеденение между сервером и клиентом при повторном соединении websockets

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, websocket

У меня есть свой мини онлайн  чат для связи между клиентом и мной, сервер написан на python а связь между сервером и клиентом происходит через js код .Но проблема этого сервера что при повторном подключении к этому серверу вылезает ошибка: `raise self.connection_closed_exc() websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: received 1001 (going away); then sent 1001 (going away)`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    const messagesContainer = document.querySelector("#messages_container");
    const messageInput = document.querySelector("[name=message_input]");
    const sendMessageButton = document.querySelector("[name=send_message_button]");

    
    let websocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");

    websocketClient.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Client connected');
        sendMessageButton.onclick = () =>{
            websocketClient.send(messageInput.value);
            messageInput.value = "";
        };
        
    };
    websocketClient.onmessage = (message) =>{
        const newMessage = document.createElement('div'); 
        newMessage.innerHTML = message.data;
        messagesContainer.appendChild(newMessage);
    };

    
    
}, false);
```

САМ СЕРВЕР PYTHON

```js
import websockets

import asyncio
print('LIVE')
all_clients = set()


async def send_message(message: str):
    for client in all_clients:
        await client.send(message)


async def new_client_connected(client_socket: websockets.WebSocketClientProtocol,  path: str):
    print("New client connected!")
    print(client_socket)
    all_clients.add(client_socket)
    while True:
        new_message = await client_socket.recv()
        print("New Message", new_message)
        await send_message(message=new_message)
async def start_server():
    await websockets.serve(new_client_connected, 'localhost', 12345)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
    event_loop.run_forever()
```